# How can I filter object elements by multi-attributes in JSON Array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to filter JSON objects in array by its multi-attributes. Below is example data and basic filters:

```
with data (id, extra_info) as (
values 
  (1, '[{"name": "class", "value": 3}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 2"}, {"name": "batch", "value": 20070102}]'::jsonb), 
  (2, '[{"name": "class", "value": 2}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 3"}, {"name": "batch", "value": 20081123}]'::jsonb), 
  (3, '[{"name": "class", "value": 3}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 1"}]'::jsonb) 
)
select *
from data
where extra_info @> '[{"name": "class", "value": 3}]'::Jsonb and 
      extra_info @> '[{"name": "batch", "value": 20070102}]'::Jsonb
```

All objects in JSON array has same structure.
But now I want to **get JSON objects with "name"="class" and "value" > 2**, how can I do it? The "value" attribute may be string, int, float and boolean.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test value be boolean or string. number is quite simple.

```
WITH data (
    id,
    extra_info
) AS (
    VALUES (1, '[{"name": "class", "value": 3}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 2"}, {"name": "batch", "value": "test_str"}]'::jsonb),
        (2, '[{"name": "class", "value": true}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 3"}, {"name": "batch", "value": 20081123}]'::jsonb),
        (3, '[{"name": "class", "value": 3}, {"name": "dept", "value": "No. 1"}]'::jsonb))
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data
WHERE
    jsonb_path_exists(extra_info, '$[*] ? (@.name == $var1 && @.value == $var2)', vars => '{"var1": "class", "var2": true}')
        OR jsonb_path_exists(extra_info, '$[*] ? (@.name == $var1 && @.value == $var2)', vars => '{"var1": "batch", "var2": "test_str"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` in a subquery:

```
select d.* from data d where exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(d.extra_info) v 
where ((v.value -> 'name')::text = '"class"' and (v.value -> 'value')::text::int > 2) or ((v.value -> 'name')::text = '"batch"' and (v.value -> 'value')::text::int > 20071010))
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ed3e7185cbf1902827ce53382827112).

Comment: Thank you! It works, but how can I combine more conditions use jsonb_array_elements? for example to get JSON objects with ("name"="class" and "value" > 2) and ("name"="batch" and "value" > 20071010)? there are more than one object it should contains.

Comment: @kyleqian If I understand correctly, you can use an `or` condition with your two `name` and `value` criteria. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
and extra_info @? '$[*] ? (@.name == "class" && @.value > 2)'
```

Note that this won't work if value isn't a number (as shown in the sample data) inside the JSON